# Why is my view controller showing blank screen after a push and its very slow on simulator?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

View Controller blank when pushing using this method if you look at the rowslected method im pushing the chat view controller but for some reason the view is being very slow in the simulator and coming through just blank none of the controls are loaded on it.

Any ideas what is up??? I just dunno why the view would act slow also what is the best way of dealing with this if I was to be loading a parse object in ordinary .net I would normally pass the entity as parameter of form is it the same here ?

```c#
using System;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.Drawing;
using Xamarin.Contacts;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExampleProject3
{
    partial class mychatcontroller : UITableViewController
    {
        List<Contact> list;
        private UIAlertView alert;
        UIDetailsChatView chatController;

        public mychatcontroller (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            list = new List<Contact>();

            //
            // get the address book, which gives us access to the
            // the contacts store
            //
            var book = new AddressBook ();

            book.RequestPermission().ContinueWith (t =>
            {
                if (!t.Result)
                {
                    alert = new UIAlertView ("Permission denied", "User has denied this app access to their contacts", null, "Close");
                    alert.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (Contact  contact in book.Take(10))
                    {
                        list.Add(contact);
                    }

                    mychat.DataSource = new TableViewDataSource (list);
                    mychat.ReloadData();
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }



        //
        // simple table view data source using the List<Contact> as the datasource
        //
        private class TableViewDataSource : UITableViewDataSource
        {
            static NSString cellIdentifier = new NSString ("contactIdentifier");
            private List<Contact> list;

            public TableViewDataSource (List<Contact> list)
            {
                this.list = list;
            }

            public override int RowsInSection (
                    UITableView tableview, int section)
            {
                return list.Count;
            }

            public override UITableViewCell GetCell (
                    UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
            {
                UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier);
                if (cell == null)
                {
                    cell = new UITableViewCell (
                            UITableViewCellStyle.Default,
                            cellIdentifier);
                }

                cell.TextLabel.Text = list[indexPath.Row].DisplayName;

                cell.ImageView.Image =list [indexPath.Row].GetThumbnail ()  ;

                Email firstEmail = list[indexPath.Row].Emails.FirstOrDefault();
                if(firstEmail != null)
                {
                    cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = String.Format("{0}: {1}", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(firstEmail.Label), firstEmail.Address);
                }

                return cell;
            }               
        }

        public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            //WHAT TO DO HERE
            UIDetailsChatView myDetail = new UIDetailsChatView();
            NavigationController.PushViewController (myDetail, true);

            tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true); // normal iOS behaviour is to remove the blue highlight
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
        }
    }
}
```

chat view controller

```c#
using System;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;

namespace ExampleProject3
{
    partial class UIDetailsChatView : UIViewController
    {
        public UIDetailsChatView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public UIDetailsChatView () 
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you build UIDetailsChatView in the designer?

Comment: @jason Hi its a view in the storyboard designer hooked up to that custom class